# Truncate not workng in MySQL

Tags: sql, oracle, truncated

I guess the correct way of truncating a value in MySQL is `truncate(value,limit);` but that doesn't seem to be working here it needs an extra table name;

```
select truncate(94204.27348,2);
```

> ERROR at line1:
>   ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Do you mean round? `SELECT ROUND(94204.27348, 2);`?

Comment: Error number starting with ORA sounds like oracle db not MySQL ?!

Comment: If this is actually Oracle, you need `FROM dual`. Also, there doesn't appear to be a `TRUNCATE` function in PL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql You should use `round`. `Truncating` table will remove the data from the table and reset all your auto increment values.

```
SELECT ROUND(94204.27348,2);
```

Result - 94204.27

This will round the value and display only two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Oracle, you must supply a table reference on your select query.

Oracle select queries require a table reference **always**.

You can do this....

```
Select truncate(94204.27348,2)  -- see further comment below
From dual
;
```

Dual is a special table that allows these sort of queries.

Also, I think you might mean to use the [TRUNC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm) function.

As others have pointed out, the TRUNC**ATE** query is not quite the same, it will erase the contents of the table that you supply it.